# How to set height of body to the content that it have

Tags: html, css

i am writing a google gadget in which i embed an iframe. iframe have a body element.the height of page is very large.i am unable to figure out from where this height is coming i used   "height:auto" but still height remain same. there is one css file are which can affect body height.

one code is

```
body {
    font-family: 'PT Sans';
    background-color: #acacac;
    background-image: url(i/n1.png);
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #f5f5f5;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    -moz-transition-duration: .4s;
    -o-transition-duration: .4s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: .4s;
    transition-duration: .4s;
}

body .container>.row-fluid>.span10>h4 {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    -ms-text-shadow: none;
    -o-text-shadow: none;
    -moz-text-shadow: none;
    -webkit-text-shadow: none;
    text-shadow: none;
}

body .heading-4 {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    -ms-text-shadow: none;
    -o-text-shadow: none;
    -moz-text-shadow: none;
    -webkit-text-shadow: none;
    text-shadow: none;
}

body.light {
    background-color: #ececec;
    color: #454545;
}

body.dark {
    background-color: #464646;
    color: #e6e6e6;
}

body .tabbable {
    color: #454545;
}

body .tabbable.dark {
    color: #e6e6e6;
}

body .tabbable.dark .tab-pane a {
    color: #61caff;
}

body .tabbable.dark .tab-pane a:hover {
    color: #90daff;
}

body .tabbable.grey {
    color: #f8f8f8;
}

body .tabbable.grey .tab-pane a {
    color: #61caff;
}

body .tabbable.grey .tab-pane a:hover {
    color: #90daff;
}
```

can any one please tell me how to set body height such that it will occupy space that its content occupy

.in chrome tool bar it is showing

```
/* Computed Style */

-webkit-transition-duration: 0.4000000059604645s;
body - .4s
background-attachment: fixed;
background-color: rgb(172, 172, 172);
background-image: url(http://cloudfactor9.appspot.com/i/n1.png);
color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
direction: ltr;
display: block;
font-family: 'PT Sans';
font-size: 14px;
height: 1633px;
line-height: 20px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-top: 0px;
unicode-bidi: embed;
width: 1254px;

/* Styles */
:active :hover
:focus  :visited
```

Matched CSS Rules
preview.min.css

```
body {
    font-family: 'PT Sans';
    background-color: #acacac;
    background-image: url('http://cloudfactor9.appspot.com/i/n1.png');
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #f5f5f5;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    <strike> -moz-transition-duration: .4s;</strike>
    <strike>-o-transition-duration: .4s;</strike>
    -webkit-transition-duration: .4s;
    <strike>transition-duration: .4s;</strike>
}
```

bootstrap.min.css

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    <strike>font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;</strike>
    <strike>font-size: 14px;</strike>
    line-height: 20px;
    <strike>color: #333;</strike>
    <strike>background-color: #fff;</strike>
}

ifr

body {    
    <strike>margin: 0px;</strike>
    padding: 0px;
    <strike>background-color: white;</strike>
}

body, td, div, span, p {
    <strike>font-family: arial,sans-serif;</strike>
}

body[Attributes Style] {
    direction: ltr;
    unicode-bidi: embed;
    <strike>margin-right: 0px;</strike>
    <strike>margin-left: 0px;</strike>
    <strike>margin-bottom: 0px;</strike>
    <strike>margin-top: 0px;</strike>
}
```

user agent stylesheet

```
body {
    display: block;
    <strike>margin: 8px;</strike>
}
```

Inherited from html

```
html {
    <strike>font-size: 100%;</strike>
}
```

i read a good book on css but doesn't work much.when i add style="height:auto;" in body then i think it should make height of body to the content available but it is not shortening the height to the body how to make height of body element to the content that it have. please guideline

Comment: strike element representing a line through that rule please understand

Comment: Why do you need to adjust the `body` height? I would suggest looking for an alternative solution. Perhaps wrap the content in a `div` and then float that `div`. Its height will then by the height of its contents.

Comment: ok i wrap it in a div then how to use float it is for right and left na ??

Comment: `float: left` will float that div to the left. Set the `width: 100%` if you want the `div` to be the full width of the page.